# Jenkinsfile ,by using sh, says No such file or directory, but it exists

Tags: linux, jenkins

I'm studying jenkins, trying to package a maven project to a war, then move it to a previously started tomcat webapps directory(/opt/tomcat/latest/webpass), but it reports 'No such file or directory'.

Already find out what causes this, but don't know why. Jenkins don't use the same filesystem as original?

Here is my troubleshooting:

1、I create a directory in my linux server under `/` as `temp20190808`.

2、then in jenkins file add `sh 'ls / -l'`, there is no `temp20190808`,also the description of each file in ls form show differenly compare with original(there are details under).

3、using jenkins file, i create a file under `/` as `jenkinstmp2019`, then `ls / -l`, it's there, but after rm the code of creating `jenkinstmp2019`, then rebuild, `ls / -l`, `jenkinstmp2019` no longer there, so the jenkins file system is a onetime job?

Here are code elaboration on point 1,2:

in my linux server, using `ls / -l`, there is a tmp20190808 i just created.

```
total 24
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Jun 19 16:53 bin -> usr/bin
dr-xr-xr-x.   5 root root 4096 Aug  1 04:55 boot
drwxr-xr-x.  17 root root 2860 Aug  7 02:48 dev
drwxr-xr-x.  86 root root 8192 Aug  7 20:52 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   4 root root   46 Jul 12 08:12 home
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    7 Jun 19 16:53 lib -> usr/lib
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    9 Jun 19 16:53 lib64 -> usr/lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Apr 11  2018 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Apr 11  2018 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root   53 Jul 23 08:11 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 101 root root    0 Aug  7 02:47 proc
dr-xr-x---.   7 root root  215 Aug  6 02:53 root
drwxr-xr-x.  28 root root  920 Aug  8 02:03 run
lrwxrwxrwx.   1 root root    8 Jun 19 16:53 sbin -> usr/sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Apr 11  2018 srv
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root    0 Aug  7 02:47 sys
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    6 Aug  8 01:50 temp1
drwxrwxrwt.  20 root root 4096 Aug  8 02:23 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root   22 Aug  8 01:39 tmp20190808
drwxr-xr-x.  13 root root  155 Jun 19 16:53 usr
drwxr-xr-x.  20 root root 4096 Jul 12 07:36 var
```

in jenkins.

```
total 8448
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      19 Jun  9  2016 bin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root       6 May 30  2016 boot
-rw-------.   1 root root 8646656 Jun  9  2016 core
drwxr-xr-x.   5 root root     360 Aug  8 01:58 dev
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      66 Aug  8 01:58 etc
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root       6 May 30  2016 home
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      45 Jun  9  2016 lib
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root      34 Jun  8  2016 lib64
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root       6 Jun  8  2016 media
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root       6 Jun  8  2016 mnt
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root       6 Jun  8  2016 opt
dr-xr-xr-x. 123 root root       0 Aug  8 01:58 proc
drwx------.   1 root root      33 Aug  8 01:58 root
drwxr-xr-x.   3 root root      30 Jun  8  2016 run
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root    4096 Jun  8  2016 sbin
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root root       6 Jun  8  2016 srv
dr-xr-xr-x.  13 root root       0 Aug  7 02:47 sys
drwxrwxrwt.   1 root root      29 Jun  9  2016 tmp
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      30 Jun 10  2016 usr
drwxr-xr-x.   1 root root      41 Jun  9  2016 var
```

As you can see, it's like two totally different linux server, but it's the same one.
So i'm wondering whether jenkins create a temp virtual file server to execute it's job, so can't access to original file except it's own directory.

Comment: Jenkins doesn't create a virtual filesystem or anything like that, this feels like it's being executed on a different node. I would suggest replacing "ls / -l" with "/bin/hostname" and seeing what that returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot, by searching, i find out it's probably the problem relating to node too.Using  `/bin/hostname` do show different hostname between linux server and jenkins, and jenkins show an id `ebf8c40f8ed1 `.Now at least i have the right direction to solve the problem, and gain more understanding about jenkins.One thing confusing me is that i'm still in master node,and do nothing changes about it's config since installing jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Find out the reason by myself.
The real cause is `agent`, i before used `agent { docker { image 'XXX' } }`, which makes jenkins run its job on docker image.Then i change it to `agent any`, so job will run on the server jenkins is deployed on.